# How can I capture simple video input with audio from a capture device

Tags: ffmpeg, video-capture, v4l2

I'm using ffmpeg on Arch linux and trying to convert some old video to digital. The setup is pretty straightforward and if I connect to the capture device with VLC I get the video and audio just fine.  So now I want to capture that with ffmpeg and write it to a file so I can edit it and clean it up.  I'm only so-so familiar with ffmpeg and I've been digging through the man pages and here is where I am at.

This command captures perfect audio, but no video:

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -ac 2 -i front:CARD=Capture,DEV=0 out.mpeg
```

This command captures perfect video;

```
ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 out.mpeg
```

captures the video signal great, but with no audio.  So combining them together should give me:

```
ffmpeg -y -f alsa -ac 2 -i front:CARD=Capture,DEV=0 -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 out.mpeg
```

But that command kinda falls on it's face. I get the audio, but no video:

```
ffmpeg -y -f alsa -ac 2 -i front:CARD=Capture,DEV=0 -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 out.mpeg
ffmpeg version n4.3.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10.2.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --disable-debug --disable-static --disable-stripping --enable-amf --enable-avisynth --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-lto --enable-fontconfig --enable-gmp --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdrm --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgsm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libjack --enable-libmfx --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librav1e --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxcb --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-shared --enable-version3
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.0 : stereo
Input #0, alsa, from 'front:CARD=Capture,DEV=0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 1608093176.894565, bitrate: 1536 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x56248fe0ab80] Dequeued v4l2 buffer contains corrupted data (0 bytes).
Input #1, video4linux2,v4l2, from '/dev/video0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 995328 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Video: rawvideo (YUY2 / 0x32595559), yuyv422, 1920x1080, 995328 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> mpeg1video (native))
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (pcm_s16le (native) -> mp2 (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x56248fe0ab80] Dequeued v4l2 buffer contains corrupted data (0 bytes).
    Last message repeated 30 times
[alsa @ 0x56248fdb3840] Thread message queue blocking; consider raising the thread_queue_size option (current value: 8)
[mpeg @ 0x56248fe0dfc0] VBV buffer size not set, using default size of 230KB
If you want the mpeg file to be compliant to some specification
Like DVD, VCD or others, make sure you set the correct buffer size
Output #0, mpeg, to 'out.mpeg':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg1video, yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 30 fps, 90k tbn, 30 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 mpeg1video
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/200000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp2, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 384 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 mp2
frame=    2 fps=0.0 q=3.2 size=       0kB time=01:48:49.26 bitrate=   0.0kbits/sframe=    2 fps=2.0 q=3.2 size=       0kB time=01:48:49.26 bitrate=   0.0kbits/sframe=    2 fps=1.3 q=3.2 size=       0kB time=01:48:49.26 bitrate=   0.0kbits/sframe=    2 fps=1.0 q=3.2 size=       0kB time=01:48:49.26 bitrate=   0.0kbits/sframe=    2 fps=0.8 q=3.2 size=       0kB time=01:48:49.26 bitrate=   0.0kbits/sframe=    2 fps=0.7 q=3.2 size=       0kB time=01:48:49.26 bitrate=   0.0kbits/sframe=    2 fps=0.6 q=3.2 size=       0kB time=01:48:49.26 bitrate=   0.0kbits/sframe=    2 fps=0.5 q=3.2 size=       0kB time=01:48:49.26 bitrate=   0.0kbits/sframe=    2 fps=0.4 q=3.2 size=       0kB time=01:48:49.26 bitrate=   0.0kbits/sframe=    2 fps=0.4 q=3.2 size=       0kB time=01:48:49.26 bitrate=   0.0kbits/sframe=    2 fps=0.4 q=3.2 size=       0kB time=01:48:49.26 bitrate=   0.0kbits/sframe=    2 fps=0.3 q=3.2 size=       0kB time=01:48:49.26 bitrate=   0.0kbits/sframe=    2 fps=0.3 q=3.2 size=       0kB time=01:48:49.26 bitrate=   0.0kbits/sframe=    2 fps=0.3 q=3.2 size=       0kB time=01:48:49.26 bitrate=   0.0kbits/sframe=    2 fps=0.3 q=3.2 size=       0kB time=01:48:49.26 bitrate=   0.0kbits/sframe=    2 fps=0.2 q=3.2 size=       0kB time=01:48:49.26 bitrate=   0.0kbits/sframe=    2 fps=0.2 q=3.2 size=       0kB time=01:48:49.26 bitrate=   0.0kbits/sframe=    2 fps=0.2 q=3.2 size=       0kB time=01:48:49.26 bitrate=   0.0kbits/sframe=    2 fps=0.2 q=3.2 size=       0kB time=01:48:49.26 bitrate=   0.0kbits/sframe=    2 fps=0.2 q=3.2 size=       0kB time=01:48:49.26 bitrate=   0.0kbits/sframe=    2 fps=0.2 q=3.2 size=       0kB time=01:48:49.26 bitrate=   0.0kbits/sframe=    2 fps=0.2 q=3.2 size=       0kB time=01:48:49.26 bitrate=   0.0kbits/sframe=    2 fps=0.2 q=3.2 size=       0kB time=01:48:49.26 bitrate=   0.0kbits/sframe=    2 fps=0.2 q=3.2 size=       0kB time=01:48:49.26 bitrate=   0.0kbits/sframe=    2 fps=0.2 q=3.2 size=       0kB time=01:48:49.26 bitrate=   0.0kbits/sframe=    2 fps=0.2 q=3.2 size=       0kB time=01:48:49.26 bitrate=   0.0kbits/sframe=    2 fps=0.1 q=3.2 size=       0kB time=01:48:49.26 bitrate=   0.0kbits/sframe=    2 fps=0.1 q=3.2 size=       0kB time=01:48:49.26 bitrate=   0.0kbits/sframe=    2 fps=0.1 q=3.2 size=       0kB time=01:48:49.26 bitrate=   0.0kbits/sframe=    2 fps=0.1 q=3.2 size=       0kB time=01:48:49.26 bitrate=   0.0kbits/sframe=    2 fps=0.1 q=3.2 size=       0kB time=01:48:49.26 bitrate=   0.0kbits/sframe=    2 fps=0.1 q=3.2 size=       0kB time=01:48:49.26 bitrate=   0.0kbits/sframe=    2 fps=0.1 q=3.2 size=       0kB time=01:48:49.26 bitrate=   0.0kbits/sframe=    2 fps=0.1 q=3.2 size=       0kB time=01:48:49.26 bitrate=   0.0kbits/sframe=    2 fps=0.1 q=3.2 size=       0kB time=01:48:49.26 bitrate=   0.0kbits/sframe=    2 fps=0.1 q=3.2 size=       0kB time=01:48:49.26 bitrate=   0.0kbits/sframe=    2 fps=0.1 q=3.2 size=       0kB time=01:48:49.26 bitrate=   0.0kbits/sframe=    2 fps=0.1 q=3.2 size=       0kB time=01:48:49.26 bitrate=   0.0kbits/sframe=    2 fps=0.1 q=3.2 size=       0kB time=01:48:49.26 bitrate=   0.0kbits/sframe=    2 fps=0.1 q=3.2 size=       0kB time=01:48:49.26 bitrate=   0.0kbits/sframe=    2 fps=0.1 q=3.2 size=       0kB time=01:48:49.26 bitrate=   0.0kbits/sframe=    2 fps=0.1 q=3.2 size=       0kB time=01:48:49.26 bitrate=   0.0kbits/sframe=    2 fps=0.1 q=3.2 size=       0kB time=01:48:49.26 bitrate=   0.0kbits/sframe=    2 fps=0.1 q=3.2 size=       0kB time=01:48:49.26 bitrate=   0.0kbits/sframe=    2 fps=0.1 q=3.2 size=       0kB time=01:48:49.26 bitrate=   0.0kbits/sframe=    2 fps=0.1 q=3.2 size=       0kB time=01:48:49.26 bitrate=   0.0kbits/sframe=    2 fps=0.1 q=3.2 size=       0kB time=01:48:49.26 bitrate=   0.0kbits/sframe=    2 fps=0.1 q=3.2 size=       0kB time=01:48:49.26 bitrate=   0.0kbits/sframe=    2 fps=0.1 q=3.2 size=       0kB time=01:48:49.26 bitrate=   0.0kbits/sframe=    2 fps=0.1 q=3.2 size=       0kB time=01:48:49.26 bitrate=   0.0kbits/sframe=    2 fps=0.1 q=3.2 size=       0kB time=01:48:49.26 bitrate=   0.0kbits/sframe=    2 fps=0.1 q=3.2 size=       0kB time=01:48:49.26 bitrate=   0.0kbits/sframe=    2 fps=0.1 q=3.2 size=       0kB time=01:48:49.26 bitrate=   0.0kbits/sframe=    2 fps=0.1 q=3.2 size=       0kB time=01:48:49.26 bitrate=   0.0kbits/sframe=    2 fps=0.1 q=3.2 size=       0kB time=01:48:49.26 bitrate=   0.0kbits/sframe=    2 fps=0.1 q=3.2 size=       0kB time=01:48:49.26 bitrate=   0.0kbits/sframe=    2 fps=0.1 q=3.2 size=       0kB time=01:48:49.26 bitrate=   0.0kbits/sframe=    2 fps=0.1 q=3.2 size=       0kB time=01:48:49.26 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x56248fe0ab80] Thread message queue blocking; consider raising the thread_queue_size option (current value: 8)
[mpeg @ 0x56248fe0dfc0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=0 size=36451
[mpeg @ 0x56248fe0dfc0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=2020 size=36451
[mpeg @ 0x56248fe0dfc0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=4061 size=36451
[mpeg @ 0x56248fe0dfc0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=6102 size=36451
[mpeg @ 0x56248fe0dfc0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=8143 size=36451
[mpeg @ 0x56248fe0dfc0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=10184 size=36451
[mpeg @ 0x56248fe0dfc0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=12225 size=36451
[mpeg @ 0x56248fe0dfc0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=14266 size=36451
[mpeg @ 0x56248fe0dfc0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=16307 size=36451
[mpeg @ 0x56248fe0dfc0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=18348 size=36451
[mpeg @ 0x56248fe0dfc0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=20389 size=36451
[mpeg @ 0x56248fe0dfc0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=22430 size=36451
[mpeg @ 0x56248fe0dfc0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=24471 size=36451
[mpeg @ 0x56248fe0dfc0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=26512 size=36451
[mpeg @ 0x56248fe0dfc0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=28553 size=36451
[mpeg @ 0x56248fe0dfc0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=30594 size=36451
[mpeg @ 0x56248fe0dfc0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=32635 size=36451
[mpeg @ 0x56248fe0dfc0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=34676 size=36451
frame=    2 fps=0.1 q=2.0 Lsize=    1470kB time=01:48:49.30 bitrate=   1.8kbits/s speed= 221x    
video:63kB audio:1388kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 1.314351%
Exiting normally, received signal 2.
```

what I would ideally like is just a fairly raw 2ch stereo "dump" of what comes through the capture card.

As always, I super appreciate any advice

Comment: Do you require mpeg-1 video in mpg container? Or will other formats suffice?

Comment: Other formats would be fine I assume so long as they can be opened and edited for things like color correction, saturation, etc.

Comment: What editor will you use?

Comment: Primarily I've been doing my touch up in OpenShot on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

You can use lossless compressed H.264, with editor friendly intra mode (`-g 1`), as an intermediate file for editing:

```
ffmpeg -y -f alsa -channels 2 -i front:CARD=Capture,DEV=0 -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 -c:v libx264 -crf 0 -g 1 -c:a copy output.mkv
```

Advantages are that it is lossless, but still compressed so it's not super big. Fast enough to encode realtime. Relatively easy to decode.

File size will be significantly bigger than typical lossy H.264, but it's only for editing and you can output a typical format for general usage from the editor.

This will work in Openshot, but probably not Premiere and the other expensive editors.